# Color switch using opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

[image: Color Switch]

I was trying to make color switch game using OpenGL.

i am stuck in using `glReadPixels();` method where i want to compare color of sphere to above rotating disk just before sphere touches disk.

plz guide me i am finding difficulty in finding exact positing where i want to readpixel color

here is how i was trying to do it.

```
unsigned char pixel[4];
glReadPixels(0, sphere_y+1, 1, 1,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixel);

cout << "R = " << ((float)pixel[0])/(float)256;
cout << "G = " << ((float)pixel[1])/ (float)256;
cout << "B = " << ((float)pixel[2])/ (float)256;
cout << "A = " << ((float)pixel[3])/ (float)256;
```

where

```
glOrtho(-10,10,-10,10,-10,10);
```

Comment: I'd advise against using `glReadPixels`. Maybe you could compute the color based on circle rotation angle instead?

Comment: Actually i am adding  some other shapes so it would be a lot easier to compare using color, otherwise i would have to check angles for every object

Answer (score 2):

The 1st and 2nd parameter of [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) are the window coordinates of the fragment in the read buffer, but not normalized device coordinates or even world or model coordinates.

You have to calculate the window coordinates of the circle.

Assuming that you know the *x* and *y* coordinate of the point in world space. The world space coordinate is the coordinate of the point transformed by the model view matrix:

```cpp
float test_x = .....; // world x coordinate
float test_y = .....; // world y coordinate
```

Since the projection (`glOrtho(-10,10,-10,10,-10,10)`) is known, the normalized device coordinates can be calculated:

```cpp
float ndc_x = test_x / 10.0f; // [-10.0, 10.0] -> [-1.0, 1.0]
float ndc_y = test_y / 10.0f; // [-10.0, 10.0] -> [-1.0, 1.0]
```

To transform this to window coordinates the width and height of the frame buffer have to be known:

```cpp
float width  = .....; // window width
float height = .....; // window height

float window_x = width  * (0.5 + 0.5 * ndc_x); // [-1.0, 1.0] -> [0.0, width]
float window_y = height * (0.5 + 0.5 * ndc_y); // [-1.0, 1.0] -> [0.0, height]

unsigned char pixel[4];
glReadPixels(window_x, window_y, 1, 1,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
```

---

Since you use [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml), I assume that you use the deprecated OpenGL fixed function pipeline.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

[`gluProject`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluProject.xml) is a handy function, to directly transform from model coordinates to window coordinates:

```cpp
float object_x = .....; // object x coordinate
float object_y = .....; // object y coordinate

GLdouble model[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model);

GLdouble proj[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, proj);

GLint view[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view);

GLdouble wnd_x, wnd_y, wnd_z;
gluProject(object_x, object_y, 0.0, model, proj, view, &wnd_x, &wnd_x, &wnd_z);

unsigned char pixel[4];
glReadPixels(wnd_x, wnd_y, 1, 1,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
```